# Add category product to breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, product, categories, breadcrumbs

On my product page I currently have a breadcrumbs that shows the following entries: Home > Shop > [product name]. I should insert the "category" (of the product) item among the breadcrumbs entries, after the "Shop" entry.
How can I do?

I have already tried to select "basic shop with category" in the WordPress permalink settings, as you can see from the screenshot, and my e-commerce page is already set as the Woocommerce "shop page".

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtZR4.png)

Despite this it is not working.
I use Jupiter theme, maybe that's what's causing the problems?